# Fix MySQL error #1064 for me

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Apparently, I have a syntax error in the following SQL statements:

```
create database project_line;

use project_line;

drop table if exists project;
create table project
(
    p_id int primary key,
    p_nm varchar(255) not null,
    p_line varchar(255) not null
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

drop table if exists meta;
create table meta
(
    m_id primary key,
    p_id not null,
    meta_nm varchar(255) not null,
    foreign key (p_id) references project (p_id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Could you point out where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the data type of `m_id` and  `p_id`

```
create table meta
(
    m_id primary key,          <------here
    p_id not null,             <------here
    meta_nm varchar(255) not null,
    foreign key (p_id) references project (p_id)
)
```

Should be  `int`.

If you use a design tool like *MySQL Workbench* for instance you will notice such errors right away since they get highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Specify Datatypes in second table. Try this sql.

```
create table project
(
    p_id int primary key,
    p_nm varchar(255) not null,
    p_line varchar(255) not null
)
ENGINE = INNODB;


create table meta
(
    m_id int primary key,
    p_id int not null,
    meta_nm varchar(255) not null,
    foreign key (p_id) references project (p_id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: Thanks man! I should probably get some sleep :/

Comment: @f1zz0_13 : you should mark post as answer whichever helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the data types for the fields "m_id" and "p_id". That's where you're error is coming. Try this:

create database project_line;

use project_line;

drop table if exists project;
create table project
(
    p_id int primary key,
    p_nm varchar(255) not null,
    p_line varchar(255) not null
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

drop table if exists meta;
create table meta
(
    m_id int primary key,
    p_id int not null,
    meta_nm varchar(255) not null,
    foreign key (p_id) references project (p_id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;